# Running a Desktop Program without RDP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, powershell, google-cloud-platform

I have a VM instance of Windows on Google Cloud. 
It runs Windows and I connect it using RDP (Remote Desktop Connection).

Yet, I have a program which takes a lot of time to load.
I can connect to the machine in Power Shell Terminal.

My question is if I can log on to desktop using Power Shell and launch a program.
Hence when I log on to the Desktop using RDP the program is already running.

Basically another problem I have is that when I close the RDP the user is logged off (Namely the desktop isn't available).

Comment: So are you asking if there's a way to connect to your instance of Windows via a shell instead of via the GUI? If so, please [edit] your question to state that more clearly.  Further, what does the text of your question have to do with its title? They don't appear related.

Comment: I edited it as I found a way to have a remote Power Shell session.